# Run Async task, before return flux db entities

Tags: java, reactive-programming, project-reactor, reactive, spring-webflux

I have `Flux<URL>`. How can I make multiple concurrent void requests for each URL (for example `myWebClient.refresh(URL)`), then (after all requests done) read data from the database and return `Flux<MyAnyEntity>` (for example `repo.findAll()`)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can achieve that using `Flux`/`Mono` operators:

```
// get the URIs from somewhere
Flux<URI> uris = //...

Flux<MyAnyEntity> entities = uris
                // map each URI to a HTTP client call and do nothing with the response
                .flatMap(uri -> webClient.get().uri(uri).exchange().then())
                // chain that call with a call on your repository
                .thenMany(repo.findAll());
```

**Update:**

This code is naturally asynchronous, non-blocking so all operations in the `flatMap` operator will be executed concurrently, according to the demand communicated by the consumer (this is the backpressure we're talking about).

If the Reactive Streams `Subscriber` `request(N)` elements, then `N` requests might be executed concurrently. I don't think this is not something you want to deal with directly, although you can influence things using windowing operators for micro-bacthing operations.

Using `.subscribeOn(Schedulers.parallel())` will not improve concurrency in this case - [as stated in the reference documentation](http://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/reference/#threading) you should only use that for CPU-bound work.

Comment: Tnx, this is what I need. But what about parallel requests? Something similar to
Stream.parallel(). I tried to add `.subscribeOn(Schedulers.parallel())`, but it does not help.

Comment: updated my answer with more information; what makes you think many requests aren't done in parallel currently? You can add a `log` operator here: `.exchange().log().then()` and you should see HTTP responses being received.

Comment: I understood my mistake. Thank you very much for your answer!